# Finding fields in report builder

Tags: ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

One of the columns in my Table actually has a value which is picks from a field from dataset and a textbox (for example =Fields!Total.Value/ReportItems!Textbox80.Value). The Total Field comes from a dataset in my report however I am struggling to find the Textbox80 . Is there any way I can search for this Textbox from Report builder UI. I tried seeing in Properties view as well but Could not find a way. I looked at below link also for help but it talks about BIDS which I cant see in Report builder

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a potential duplicate of [How do I find a specific textbox within a SSRS 2008 R2 Report](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13182895/9606612)

The answers show that there is no specific way to do this with the report builder UI without selecting each report item and manually checking the properties menu.

The textbox can easily be seen if you are viewing the report in Visual studio (using the properties drop down box at the top of the screen)

The textbox can also be found if you edit the .rdl file in a text editor, which can then allow you to attempt to locate the textbox